# When mailing a job to a friend, the body of the message contains HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Today I came across a job posting that I wanted to refer to a colleague, so I clicked on the helpful mail to a friend link; and I got this in my default email client:

[image]

*Please excuse my poor hand drawn arrows.*

I'm not sure if this is isolated to the [specific job posting](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/133457/software-engineer-python-core-and-full-stack-jrd-group) or a more general issue.

Comment: that seems more like what the employer has put in where they have used `&nbsp;` which renders in HTML as a space. you'll see where that line is infront of the word *"front"* there's 2 spaces....though not sure why the employer has typed it out (or even generated it) like that and all SO has done in generating the email body is grab like the first 200 characters (though the character count to be is on 199)

Comment: I am not sure if this is something they typed or a result of some copy-paste cleanup.

Comment: there's no freehand circle, but I'll take a look anyway

Comment: @AurélienGasser wiggly arrows is the new circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Thanks for your report!